# Unresolved external symbol in C++, error LNK1120 and LNK2001

Tags: c++

I fail to understand as why I get LNK1120: Unresolved externals and LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol error messages for the following code in C++

```
class base
{
public:
    static int x;
    void fun()
    {
       base::x = 10;
       cout << base::x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base b;
    b.fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same code works if I remove _static_, so seems like it has to do something with static class member

Comment: Definitely to do with `static` member!

Comment: Skip down to answer two in the duplicate, specifically **static data members must be defined outside the class in a single translation unit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a `static` member in a class, you have to also provide a ***definition*** outside the class declaration; like this:

```
class base
{
public:
    static int x; // DECLARES the variable
    void fun()
    {
       x = 10; // You don't need the base:: prefix inside the class!
       cout << x;
    }
};
int base::x = 0; // DEFINES the variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared x inside the class. Since it's a static variable you must allocat it's memory outside the class scope.

Just add:
base::x = 0; 
After you close the base class.

Comment: You mean `int base::x = 0;`