# C++ undefined reference when calling a function

Tags: c++, function

I have a class `router.cpp` with implementations of dijkstras algorithm called `getShortestPath`.
I would like to call this method from another .cpp file called `interface.cpp`.

**Router.h**

```
public:
    Router(vector<double>);
    void getShortestPath(...):
```

I defined **starter.h** as:

```
#include "Router.h"
class starter {
public:
     static Router r;

     static std::string func(std::vector<double> bbox) {
        std::string a = "DONE";
        return a;
    }
};
//EDIT: definition of a static variable must be given outside class declaration
 Router r = starter::r;
```

and **interface.cpp** where I am trying to call `getShortestPath`:

```
starter starter;
std::vector<double> bbox;
//starter::router =   
starter::r.getShortestPath(); // ERROR HERE "undefined reference to 'starter::r'
```

How should I define router appropriately?

How can I overcome this issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

After the helpful comments, kindly find the updated definition of the static variable above.

This leaves me with the same error as before:

undefined reference to `starter::r` at `starter::r.getShortestPath();`

Comment: static members can be declared inside the class definition, but they must often be defined exactly once outside the class definition. Add `Router starter::r;` to a cpp file. router.cpp seems the mos logical place to put it.

Comment: **Very** similar issue recently addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937147/unresolved-external-symbol-in-c-error-lnk1120-and-lnk2001/57937200#57937200

Comment: Side note: When you find yourself making classes entirely of static members, that's usually a sign you want a namespace instead.

Comment: Skip down to answer two in the duplicate, specifically **static data members must be defined outside the class in a single translation unit**

Comment: @user4581301 should it be `Router starter::r;` or `Router starter::r {  the vector I need for the constructor } ;` ?

Comment: If you have arguments for the constructor, that's the place to use them.